# If graph of $f(x) \cdot f'(x)$ is given, answer the following

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $f(x)$ is a continuous and differentiable function. Given that $f(x)$ takes values of the type $\pm \sqrt{W}$ for $x=a$ and $x=b$ (where $W$ denotes set of whole numbers). For all other $x$, $f(x)$ can take any real value. Also $f(c)=-\frac{3}{2}$ and $|f(a)| \leq |f(b)|$ and graph of $f(x) \cdot f'(x)$ is given below:

[image]

Answer the following questions:

Ques: Find number of rational values $f(a)+f(b)+f(c)$ can take?

Ques: Find number of values $(f(a))^2+(f(b))^2+(f(c))^2$ can take?

It is clear from given data that $f'(c)=0$ . I thought of taking  $g(x)=(f(x))^2/2$ Hence from given graph, $g(x)$ increases from $x=a$ to $x=c$ and then decreases Also $g(c)=9/8$ but I am not able to proceed from here. Could someone please help me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires some bookkeeping. We have $f(c)=-\frac{3}{2}$ and, from the graph, $f'(c)=0$. Since $f$ is continuous, $f(x)<0$ for $a<x<b$, so from the graph again$$f'(x)<0\text{ for }a<x<c,\\ f'(x)>0\text{ for }c<x<b.$$ Thus we have 
$$-\frac{3}{2}<f(x)\leq 0\text{ for } a\leq x<c, \\ -\frac{3}{2}<f(x)\leq 0\text{ for } c< x\leq b, \\$$

So I think at $a$ and $b$, $f(x)$ can only be $0,-1$ or $-\sqrt{2}\ (=-1.41...>-\frac{3}{2})$. Using this, and the given fact $|f(a)|\leq |f(b)|$, you should be able to count the different possible values of $f(a)+f(c)+f(b)$ and $[f(a)]^2+[f(c)]^2+[f(b)]^2$. Can you take it from here?